# Oracle TimesTen Installation and Configuration

Tags: oracle, installation, configuration, timesten

How do I set up the environment so I can connect to TimesTen, use utilities, etc?

Comment: Did you try to ask the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/sql-developer-17.3/TTSDV/connect.htm#TTSDV111) about this?

Answer (score 0):

Various environment variables are required to be set in order to use TimesTen utilities and for applications that will connect to TimesTen. The best/easiest way to do this is to source (not run) the environment setup script:
<instance_home>/bin/ttenv.[c]sh
(on Windows run)
<instance_home>\bin\ttenv.bat